# Displaying multiple columns of data [from a PHP list] in a table in Laravel View

Tags: php, html, laravel

I currently am using a Laravel View with the following HTML that displays data onto a table using the `<td>` tag.

```
@if($unrostered)
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php $index = 1; ?>
            @foreach($unrostered as $name => $profile)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?= $index; $index++; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a
                            href="{{ $profile }}">{{ $name }}
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endif
```

I am currently just using one associative list called `$unrostered` which contains the key and value called `name` and `profile`. This shows two columns of data, like this:

[image]

As you can see, the `name` variable is the name of the person, and the `profile` is a URL that links to their profile.

My HTML skills aren't good. I want to pass in multiple lists [of the same length] into my HTML table, so each list occupies their own column.

I tried juggling the row and data tags, however, all I was able to achieve were that all the data points occupied only one row instead of columns.

Comment: How many lists you currently have? and data format of each list?

Comment: I currently have one associative list called $unrostered which is shown in the Blade template. The data format are either strings or integers.

Comment: But you mentioned in your question that "I want to pass in multiple lists". What are your multiple lists?

Comment: @tuananh I don't have them yet since I'm not sure how to display each list as columns, but they will be the same size as $unrostered. They will contain URLs

Comment: And do they have the same format as `$unrostered`? Like `$name => $url`?

Comment: @tuananh yessir, you can assume that.

Comment: And how do you want to display the `$url` in additional lists?

Comment: @tuananh it will occupy the same format as my HTML - using a href.

Comment: But what would be the name of additional links?  The links in `$unrostered` have `$name`, how about other lists?

Comment: @tuananh let's say $rank, but it shouldn't matter since I can change that later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the name of your other lists are `$list1, $list2, ...` and they have the same format as your `$unrostered`. Then your `foreach` code should be changed to:

```
        <?php $index = 1; ?>
        @foreach($unrostered as $name => $profile)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?= $index; $index++; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a
                        href="{{ $profile }}">{{ $name }}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a
                        href="{{ $list1[$name] }}">{{ $name }}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a
                        href="{{ $list2[$name] }}">{{ $name }}
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: So if I am not wrong, you are using `$list1[$name]` to get the URL and `$name` to get the name of the user?

Comment: You mentioned that all your lists have the same format of `$name => $url`, therefore `$list1[$name]` should get you the correspond `$url` of `$unrostered[$name]`

Comment: Yep, I think this works! I'll let you know further if I have any issues!